# Concavity of a real valued function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm studing von Neumann-Morgenstern utility functions. Concavity of instantaneous utility is important in the definition of risk aversion. I would like to characterise that. This sould be an easy question, but I have not been able to answer it.

Suppose that $u:R\to R$ is a continuous, increasing function that has the following property: $\forall x,\ \forall \epsilon>0\ \ u(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}u(x-\epsilon)+\frac{1}{2}u(x+\epsilon)$. Is $u(x)$ concave?

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is the same as saying that for all $x, y\in \mathbb R$, we have

$$u\bigg(\frac{x+y}{2} \bigg) \geq \frac{1}{2} u(x) + \frac{1}{2} u(y).$$

Using induction, you can show that

$$u(px + (1-p)y) \geq pu(x) + (1-p)u(y)$$

where $p$ is of the form

$$p = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{c_i}{2^i},$$

where $N\in \mathbb N$ and $c_i=0$ or $1$. For example, for $p = \frac{3}{4}$, we have

$$u\bigg(\frac{3}{4} x + \frac{1}{4}y\bigg) = u\bigg(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+y}{2}\big) \bigg)\geq \frac{1}{2}u(x) + \frac{1}{2} u\bigg(\frac{x+y}{2}\bigg) \geq \frac{3}{4} u(x) + \frac{1}{4}u(y)\ .$$

The set of all such $p$ is dense in $[0,1]$, thus by continuity of $u$,

$$u(rx + (1-r)y) \geq ru(x) + (1-r)u(y)$$

for all $r\in [0,1]$. So $u$ is concave.